# UserControl EventTrigger when Visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to get a trigger when a view (BiometricVM) becomes visible to the user. The view in question is instantiated in another view (ParentView.xaml) and hidden. I read several answers here in SO, but none of them have worked. Here is the relevant code:

ParentView.xaml

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#80000000" Visibility="{Binding BiometricViewVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <Border Style="{StaticResource DefaultWindowBorder}" >
                <Grid Background="White" >
                    <vw:BiometricView DataContext="{Binding BiometricVM}" Visibility="{Binding BiometricViewVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

ParentViewModel.cs

```
public bool BiometricViewVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _biometricViewVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _biometricViewVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BiometricViewVisible));
        }
    }
```

BiometricView.xaml

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsVisibleChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=OnLoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This is the command that is not getting called (OnLoadedCommand).

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem appears to be that `IsVisibleChanged` is a DependendyPropertyChanged event, not a `RoutedEvent`, and `i:EventTrigger` only works with routed events. `MouseDown` for example is a `RoutedEvent`: If you change `EventName` to "MouseDown", then when the control is visible a click on it should invoke `OnLoadedCommand`. Not that that helps you here. You could retreat and do it with a regular event handler, or you could write your own behavior that executes a command on a dependency property change event.

Comment: @EdPlunkett What would be the best approach to get a call to the BiometricViewModel.cs class only when the view is visible to the user?

Comment: If it's your class, use DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty to get the dpd for its Visibility property and call AddValueChanged to add a handler. That's fastest. You could generalize that as a behavior if you wanted.

Comment: It would help if you would explain: a) what it is you need to do with the visibility changes to visible, b) why you can't just respond to changes in the view model visibility property, and c) why you can't handle the `Loaded` event (which _is_ a `RoutedEvent`). As stated, your question is very broad, as there are many different ways to address the behavior described.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply invoke the command in the setter of the `BiometricViewVisible` source property?

```
public bool BiometricViewVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _biometricViewVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        _biometricViewVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BiometricViewVisible));
        if (value)
        {
            OnLoadedCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `Visibility` property of the `BiometricView` is directly bound to this source property, the view will become visible only when this property is set to true anyway so you don't need to handle any event.